# Computed column if statement "Divide"

Tags: calculated-columns

I have a row which pulls back a Decimal `if (row["Time"]` and I need an statement which divides the output by 60.

Still quite a novice do apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer for this question is:

```
  (row["TIME"]) / 60
```